# Use preLaunchTasks in flutter launch config

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am trying to run a preLaunchTask to define environment vars. The problem is that the tasks runs in a separate terminal while the flutter launch runs in the Debug Console.

Is there a way to launch the tasks in the debug console?

tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "LoadEnvVars",
            "command": "pwsh.exe",
            "args": [
                "-ExecutionPolicy",
                "Bypass",
                "-File",
                "${workspaceFolder}/load_env_vars.ps1"
            ],
        },
    ]
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "makon_front (pwsh)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": ["--dart-define",
                    "FIREBASE_WEB_CONFIG=${env:FIREBASE_CONFIG_WEB}",
                    "--dart-define",
                    "USE_FB_EMULATOR=${env:USE_FB_EMULATOR}"],
            "preLaunchTask": "LoadEnvVars"
        },
        {
            "name": "makon_front (profile mode)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "profile"
        },
        {
            "name": "makon_front (release mode)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "release"
        }
    ],
}
```

I have tested the actual string in dart pad, and it works fine. I have also ran `const bool.hasEnvironment` in the Debug Console, it returns a `false`. Clearly the env vars are not loading in the debug console before dart launch. How do I do that?

Comment: If your question is actually "_Is there a way to launch the tasks in the debug console?_", please write a title that better represents your question. See [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Comment: That is one of the possibilities. I just want to load env variables before the starting the app.

Answer (score 1):

The Debug Console is not a terminal, so apps run there cannot run in the same terminal as tasks. While it's possible to have Dart CLI scripts run in the built-in terminal, this isn't supported for Flutter (because the debugger needs to own the `flutter run` process) - although if it were, I still don't believe you could have VS Code reuse a Task terminal for a debug session.

The best way to do what you want is (as you found) definitely `--dart-define-from-file` which was added in the last version.

Answer (score 0):

Well my original goal was to load env vars through file. In Flutter 3.7, they have added the `--dart-define-from-file`, which allows you to define your environment in a json file.

```json
{
   "VAR1": "foo",
   "VAR2": "bar"
}
```